# How to fix Nuget restore for projects using different package sources within same VS solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm using VS 2017, and I have a new common project(CommonLib) that needs to be referenced by projects in multiple solutions. For this common project I want to maintain its own packages folder. And after referencing this project into an existing solution (that has a project that refers a different packages folder), nuget restore is not looking at both these package folders.

Not sure if within a single solution nuget restore could search for multiple packages folder to resolve the referencing libraries based on the project file hintPaths.
Also I see that migrating from packages.config to PackageReference would help here, but I don't want to get rid of packages.config in existing projects, and also not in the new CommonLib project to be consistent.

Here is how my src setup paths are:

```
UX.Sln - paths: C:\Src\UX\UX.Sln; C:\Src\UX\packages;
    UXSource.csproj - paths: C:\Src\UX\UXSource; This refers nuget libs from src C:\Src\UX\packages
    CommonLib.csproj - paths: C:\Src\Common\CommonLib; I want to refer nuget libs from src C:\Src\Common\packages

Api.Sln - paths: C:\Src\Api\Api.Sln; C:\Src\Api\packages;
    ApiSource.csproj - paths: C:\Src\Api\ApiSource; This refers nuget libs from src C:\Src\Api\packages
    CommonLib.csproj - paths: C:\Src\Common\CommonLib; I want to refer nuget libs from src C:\Src\Common\packages
```

Comment: Hi mv_50, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And it not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like another project doesn't have configured NuGet source. So you can use

`dotnet nuget add <source>` command [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source).

or extend it using in `NuGet.Config` file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections

Also pls try to package folder location in `nuget.config`

```
 <configuration>
      <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="$\..\pacakges" />
      </config>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Im using VS 2017 & .net fw 4.6.1, so "dotnet nuget add"  not supported from package mgr console..Tried using this cmd "nuget sources add.." but having issues running "Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine -Version 4.4.1" to install NuGet cli..so skipped this option.. On extending NuGet.config, i tried adding this file with `<config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\packages" />
  </config>` also tried with `<packageSources>
    <add key="Test Source" value="..\..\packages" />
  </packageSources>` but these didnt work..and I didnt remove packages.config when trying these..

Comment: @mv_05 I have updated answer, pls try this one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore nuget packages through multiple nuget packages sources. You just need to put custom `nuget.config` file.

**And** as you saw, [custom nuget.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) will act on the current projects under the current folder and projects under all subdirectories.

And `nuget.config` file could not be added into the project folder and it should be under solution folder or above folder to make it work.

**Besides**, it seems you have added an existing project called `CommonLib` into `UX` solution and `Api` solution.

So you could try this:

**1)** add a file called `nuget.config` under `C:\Src` and then add these node under that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="NuGet_Restore_Path1" value="C:\Src\UX\packages" />
        <add key="NuGet_Restore_Path2" value="C:\Src\Common\packages" />
        <add key="NuGet_Restore_Path3" value="C:\Src\Api\packages" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**2) Then**, the these two solution could use these packages folder to restore missing nuget packages.

Use: `nuget restore UX.sln` and `nuget restore Api.Sln`.

**In addition**, if you do not want the new `nuget.config` file affects other solutions under `src` folder, you could add the file into `C:\Src\UX` and `C:\Src\Api` instead.